# How to delay `redirection operator` of BASH `>`

Tags: bash, redirect, operator-keyword

First I create 3 files:

```
$ touch alpha bravo carlos
```

Then I want to save the list to a file:

```
$ ls > info.txt
```

However, I always got my `info.txt` inside:

```
$ cat info.txt
alpha
bravo
carlos
info.txt
```

It looks like the redirection operator creates my `info.txt` first.

In this case, my question is. How can I save my list of files before creating the `info.txt` first?

---

The main question is about the redirection operator. Why does it act first, and how to delay it so I complete my task first? Using the example above to answer it.

Comment: This is a common FAQ. There is no way to make redirections run after the command, but you can redirect to a file in a different directory (say, in `/tmp`) and then move it here.

Comment: Where can I find more info about it. It does affect other operations ? It's possible to do it in other languages like Python or C?

Comment: `ls | tee info.txt >/dev/null` does what you want. I wouldn't say it's better than what tripleee suggested, but it's an alternative.

Comment: Both answers are great! I appreciate!  I'm in computer since 90s but I still couldn't fit every piece in place, so I need more time to understand the OS, I'm not aware of "null bytes", how process works, or character encoding. So there's a tie and I don't have enough rep to upvote your answers yet.

Comment: Notice that I'm using Bash in Termux on Android 10, I don't have permission to access anything in / or /dev/null, as well I don't want this question to be an Android issue, so any Linux/Bash answer will be valid.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, `ls | tee info.txt >/dev/null` sometimes puts `info.txt` in the listing and sometimes doesn't.  It depends on how the `ls` and `tee` processes are scheduled, which is non-deterministic.  I've tested this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you redirect a command's output to a file, the shell opens a file handle to the destination file, then runs the command in a child process whose standard output is connected to this file handle. There is no way to change this order, but you can redirect to a file in a different directory if you don't want the `ls` output to include the new file.

```sh
ls >/tmp/info.txt
mv /tmp/info.txt ./
```

In a production script, you should make sure that the file name is unique and unpredictable.

```
t=$(mktemp -t lstemp.XXXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$t"' INT HUP 
ls >"$t"
mv "$t" ./info.txt
```

Alternatively, capture the output into a variable, and then write that variable to a file.

```
files=$(ls)
echo "$files" >info.txt
```

As an aside, probably [don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) If you want a list of files in the current directory

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

does that.

Comment: Globs are expanded before redirections are performed, `ls -d * >list.txt`, or even better, `printf '%s\n' * >list.txt`, would work fine too

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks, changed the wording.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is to save your command output to a variable, like this:

```
ls_output="$(ls)"
```

and then write the value of that variable to the file, using any of these commands:

```
printf '%s\n' "$ls_output" > info.txt
cat <<< "$ls_output" > info.txt
echo "$ls_output" > info.txt
```

Some caveats with this approach:

- Bash variables can't contain null bytes. If the output of the command includes a null byte, that byte and everything after it will be discarded.

  - In the specific case of `ls`, though, this shouldn't be an issue, because the output of `ls` should never contain a null byte.
- `$(...)` removes trailing newlines. The above compensates for this by adding a newline while creating `info.txt`, but if the the command output ends with *multiple* newlines, then the above will effectively collapse them into a single newline.

  - In the specific case of `ls`, this could happen if a filename ends with a newline — very unusual, and unlikely to be intentional, but nonetheless possible.
- Since the above adds a newline while creating `info.txt`, it will put a newline there even if the command output doesn't end with a newline.

  - In the specific case of `ls`, this shouldn't be an issue, because the output of `ls` should always end with a newline.

If you want to avoid the above issues, another approach is to save your command output to a temporary file in a different directory, and then move it to the right place; for example:

```
tmpfile="$(mktemp)"
ls > "$tmpfile"
mv -- "$tmpfile" info.txt
```

. . . which obviously has different caveats (e.g., it requires access to write to a different directory), but should work on most systems.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is to exclude the `info.txt` file from the  `ls` output.

If you can rename the list file to `.info.txt` then it's as simple as:

```
ls >.info.txt
```

`ls` doesn't list files whose names start with `.` by default.

If you can't rename the list file but you've got GNU `ls` then you can use:

```
ls --ignore=info.txt >info.txt
```

Failing that, you can use:

```
ls | grep -v '^info\.txt$' >info.txt
```

All of the above options have the advantage that you can safely run them after the list file has been created.

Another general approach is to capture the output of `ls` with one command and save it to the list file with a second command.  As others have pointed out, temporary files and shell variables are two specific ways to capture the output.  Another way, if you've got the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package installed, is to use the [sponge](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/moreutils/sponge.1.en.html) utility:

```
ls | sponge info.txt
```

Finally, note that you may not be able to reliably extract the list of files from `info.txt` if it contains plain `ls` output.  See [ParsingLs - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more information.